# How can I determine whether xyz.example.com uses a wildcard A record?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, subdomain

If you have many sub-domain names like `xxx.example.com`, `xyz.example.com` etc, you can solve these through server-side scripting or other means by using a wildcard A record for *.example.com in your DNS.

How can I determine whether a wildcard domain is configured for any given domain name? Using http://network-tools.com gives a lot of information, but doesn't reveal this. If I need to use commandline tools: I use Windows. One such example that uses a wildcard domain DNS, I think, is blogspot.com.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can literally query "*.example.com" and find out if there *is* a wildcard, but it is impossible to tell the difference between these two zones:

```
xyz.example.com.  IN A  1.2.3.4
*.example.com.    IN A  1.2.3.4
```

and

```
*.example.com.    IN A  1.2.3.4
```

i.e., you can't find out whether you're being answered **by** a wildcard for a given query, only that a wildcard exists.

I haven't found any Web-accessible looking glasses that support it yet, as they seem to think it's invalid input, but raw dig (or even nslookup on Windows) works like a charm:

```
c:\Some\User> nslookup
> *.my-test-domain.com
Server:  Wireless_Broadband_Router.home
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    *.my-test-domain-is-not-a-real-domain.com
Address:  1.2.3.4
```

Or with dig:

```
# dig +short '*.not-a-real-domain.com'
1.2.3.4
```

Comment: +1: for valuable insight. Could you elaborate and also explain me *how*  I could do such a query, or what online network/dns tools support such query (tried, but didn't find it myself)?

Comment: Using nslookup, I get a list of aliases, for instance, `*.blogspot.com` returns an alias with the same name. Using `shore.blogspot.com` returns an alias with the same name. Both receive an answer of `Name: blogspot.l.google.com`. When I use `*.undermyhat.org`, no aliases are given, but the answer is `Name: *.undermyhat.org`. Do I understand this correctly that blogspot uses wildcard aliases (CNAME) and undermyhat uses wildcard A records?

Comment: Using dig, you can see more of the return code.  I'll put it in an answer so I get formatting, but mark this one as the answer, not mine :)

Answer (score 4):

In response to BMDan's good answer:

```
houdini@linode:~/ > dig '*.blogspot.com' +noall +answer
*.blogspot.com.         3352    IN      CNAME   blogspot.l.google.com.
blogspot.l.google.com.  52      IN      A       72.14.204.191
houdini@linode:~/ > ^blogspot.com^undermyhat.org
dig '*.undermyhat.org' +noall +answer
*.undermyhat.org.       14400   IN      A       83.222.226.157
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my latest questions in a separate post. Seems like `dig` can indeed get quite a bit more. Hmm, CygWin? I'll google some Windows alternatives and meanwhile use my Linux vm.